# opencv pyqt video normal frame rate

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, opencv3.0

I’m creating a special purpose video player in Python 3.6 using OpenCV3 and ffmepg for handling the images and using PyQt5 for the Windows environment.  I chose this combination of packages because ffmpeg handles a wider variety of codecs than QtMultimedia.

I’ve run into one snag.  My player does not play at regular speed – it plays at roughly ¾ of normal speed.  I use QTimer.timer to loop my display engine (nextFrameSlot) at a speed of 1/framerate.

Any suggestions on how to get the video to play at regular speed?  Here is an abbreviated set of code that demonstrates my problem.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QFormLayout, QPushButton, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QMessageBox, QApplication, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
import cv2


class VideoCapture(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, filename, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(str(filename[0]))
        self.length = int(self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        self.frame_rate = self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        #self.codec = self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC)
        self.video_frame = QLabel()
        parent.layout.addWidget(self.video_frame)

    def nextFrameSlot(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
        pix = QPixmap.fromImage(img)
        self.video_frame.setPixmap(pix)

    def start(self):
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.nextFrameSlot)
        self.timer.start(1000.0/self.frame_rate)

    def pause(self):
        self.timer.stop()

    def deleteLater(self):
        self.cap.release()
        super(QWidget, self).deleteLater()

class VideoDisplayWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(VideoDisplayWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QFormLayout(self)
        self.startButton = QPushButton('Start', parent)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(parent.startCapture)
        self.startButton.setFixedWidth(50)
        self.pauseButton = QPushButton('Pause', parent)
        self.pauseButton.setFixedWidth(50)
        self.layout.addRow(self.startButton, self.pauseButton)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

class ControlWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ControlWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyTrack")

        self.capture = None

        self.isVideoFileLoaded = False

        self.quitAction = QAction("&Exit", self)
        self.quitAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        self.quitAction.triggered.connect(self.closeApplication)

        self.openVideoFile = QAction("&Open Video File", self)
        self.openVideoFile.setShortcut("Ctrl+Shift+V")
        self.openVideoFile.triggered.connect(self.loadVideoFile)

        self.mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        self.fileMenu = self.mainMenu.addMenu('&File')
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.openVideoFile)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.quitAction)

        self.videoDisplayWidget = VideoDisplayWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.videoDisplayWidget)

    def startCapture(self):
        if not self.capture and self.isVideoFileLoaded:
            self.capture = VideoCapture(self.videoFileName, self.videoDisplayWidget)
            self.videoDisplayWidget.pauseButton.clicked.connect(self.capture.pause)
        self.capture.start()

    def endCapture(self):
        self.capture.deleteLater()
        self.capture = None

    def loadVideoFile(self):
        try:
            self.videoFileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Select a Video File')
            self.isVideoFileLoaded = True
        except:
            print ("Please Select a Video File")

    def closeApplication(self):
        choice = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message','Do you really want to exit?',QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
            print("Closing....")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ControlWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: have you profiled how long `nextFrameSlot()` takes to run?

Comment: MP4 file, 1280x720, avc1 codec, 29.97 fps: avg = 12.6msec, stdev = 9msec.
            AVI file, 640x480, XVID codec, 30 fps: avg = 3ms, stdev = 2 msec.

Comment: Update:  Those avg and stdev numbers quoted above are for nextFrameSlot only.  When the additional time required for QTimer.timer increases the overall cycle time to about 47 msec, which exceeds the required 33 msec.  Is there a faster way to invoke calling nextFrameSlot  other than QTimer.timer?

Comment: I'm surprised there is that much overhead in the timer. You could try injecting directly into the event loop with a high priority using `QCoreApplication.postEvent()`

Comment: As it turns out, QTimer does not add the overhead.  Still looking for the problem.  I timed a simple 10 msec loop with QTimer.timer and it rn in 10 msec (as it should).  My nextFrameSlot runs significantly less that 33 msec.  I's still trying to diagnose where the delay is.  I'll have to strip the code down to the barest possible and build it up gradually.

Comment: It's possible it is an interaction between the QTimer and the length of time your slot takes to run. Windows timers are limited to about 15msec of precision, which is not very good. It is possible the longer slot run times result in the next QTimer not running as soon as it should. I think you'll probably need to subclass QTimer so you can see when it fires and when your slot runs. Alternatively, if reading the frame is a blocking call, then that will naturally set the frame rate based on the video source and you might be able to do away with the timer altogether.

Comment: Solved - I needed to specify `self.timer.setTimerType(Qt.PreciseTimer)`.  By default, QTimer() uses a coarse timer.  For Windows, the coarse time is 15.6 msec intervals.

Comment: That's really useful to know. You should post it as an answer and then mark it as the accepted answer as comments may not stay around forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved - I needed to specify `self.timer.setTimerType(Qt.PreciseTimer)` after the statement `self.timer = QTimer()` in the function `start(self)`. By default, QTimer() uses a coarse timer. For Windows, the coarse time is 15.6 msec intervals.